# Can we set a cookie in php according to client's time?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I have following requirements:

1. create a cookie for server domain
2. that cookie will expire in x seconds say in 200 or 500 seconds.

Problem is, that clients can lag as much as many minutes behind server. On server side I am setting cookie as

```
setcookie($cooName,$cooVal,time()+500,"/");
```

but now if client computer is 500 seconds behind server, above code will effect into a cookie which will expire in 1000 seconds not 500 seconds.

I was thinking to send client's time stamp to server and set cookie on that time. something like this:

```
setcookie($cooName,$cooVal,$_GET['clientTS']+500,"/");
```

But if client is 500 seconds behind, and if I set such a cookie which is backdated it does not get set. How to achieve a time sync between client and server in case of cookie expiry?

Comment: That's actually an excellent question. You can generate the JavaScript to do it, that's for sure. But I'm pretty positive you can't do it in PHP alone.

Comment: @Truth maybe if you set the timezone to the client timezone?

Comment: That still doesn't guarantee that the time will be identical to the user's time. Only JavaScript can know that (or he can pass it in a form, but don't count on it if it's critical).

Comment: @mugur what if users from different timezones access the server?

Comment: What if you set the cookie in javascript with `document.cookie = ...`

Comment: @emaillenin he can keep the timezone in a session variable

Comment: What you are trying to do can be achieved using the Max-Age attribute. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#74401

Comment: thanks for all comments, I will try your suggestion soon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, *Expires* is an absolute date and depends on the user agent’s local date. As you have concluded correctly, this could lead to an inaccurate cookie expiry.

This is also the reason why IETF’s first standardization of [Netscape’s original proposal](http://web.archive.org/web/20020803110822/http://wp.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html), replaced the absolute expiration date by a relative expiration date, the *Max-Age* attribute that specified the time in delta seconds from the point in time the cookie has been issued. [RFC 2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965), that obsoleted RFC 2109, did the same. Just as [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265), that is currently the most recent specification for cookies.

Cookies as per RFC 6265 do also allow to specify the expiry date by both a relative date using *Max-Age* and a absolute date using *Expires*, the latter primarily for backwards compatibility:

> If a cookie has both the Max-Age and the Expires attribute, the Max-Age attribute has precedence and controls the expiration date of the cookie.

So you could write your own function that mimics this behavior:

```
$maxage = 12345;
$expires = date(DATE_COOKIE, time()+$maxage);
header("Set-Cookie: $name=$value, Expires=$expires, Max-Age=$maxage, …");
```

---

Here’s an example function:

```
function set_cookie($name, $value=null, $maxage=null, $path=null, $domain=null, $secure=false, $httponly=false) {
    $cookie = rawurlencode($name) . '=' . rawurlencode($value);
    $attributes = array();
    if (!is_null($maxage)) {
        $maxage = intval($maxage);
        $attributes[] = 'Expires='.date(DATE_COOKIE, $maxage > 0 ? time()+$maxage : 0);
        $attributes[] = 'Max-Age='.$maxage;
    }
    if (!is_null($path)) {
        $attributes[] = 'Path='.rawurlencode($path);
    }
    if (!is_null($domain)) {
        $attributes[] = 'Domain='.rawurlencode($domain);
    }
    if ($secure) {
        $attributes[] = 'Secure';
    }
    if ($httponly) {
        $attributes[] = 'HttpOnly';
    }
    header('Set-Cookie: '.implode('; ', array_merge(array($cookie), $attributes)), false);
}
```

Comment: Correct - the `Max-Age` attribute is the correct way to achieve this.

Comment: If you write your own cookie function, don't for get to `rawurlencode` the name and value.

Comment: @Shades88 I don’t know which browsers do already support *Max-Age* (at all and in combination with *Expires* as per RFC 6265). Maybe you find some information on it.

Comment: Yes, I have hit a roadblock with IEs. Not supporting max-age!! Why is god keeping something as sinister as IE on this planet!! :'(

Comment: @Shades88 That’s why RFC 6265 allows to combine both *Max-Age* and *Expires*.

Comment: yeah. but expires is creating problems. So I resorted to your solution. everything was awesome until I came across that menacing 'e' ;). Anyways, Now I have settled on a solution where I store cookie start time and expire time in seconds. check it on server side, and destroy the cookie. Now one more problem is that, for this all i am creating session cookies. and these session cookies are not deleted when we clear browser history in IE. That's not a problem but causes delay while testing. One more weird feature of IE